# Cannot get the html from WKWebView in Swift

Tags: html, swift, wkwebview

Unfortunately, I cannot get the web page html from the web view with this code:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

In the web page there are two html codes and the one that I want to extract is the one that is inside another html code please see below:

[image]

I have also tried another codes such as:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML
```

but nothing of these worked, and I still cannot get the inner html.

Comment: Have you tried using Jsoup library?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from the iframe tag, inside the iframe tag is a link, which the view will be loaded from that link.
I had to extract the link from the iframe tag and then load it inside the webView, then I could get the access to the html from that part.